# Не получается выставить JDK 1.8 в AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, java

В проекте необходимо выставить восьмую Java. Скачал и установил все как надо, но когда пытаюсь выставить в Project Structure -> JDK Location путь к jdk1.8.0_101, студия не запоминает эту установку, то есть я выбрал нужный путь, нажал ОК, снова вошел в Project Structure, и путь сбросился к JDK 1.7
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве проблема не в пути до Android sdk? Студия вон пишет что путь до sdk не должен содержать пробелов. Ну и судя по скрину, то путь до JDK указывает на jdk1.8.0_101.

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать ответ, а то у меня в Android Studio то же самое. JDK 1.7 ставится, а JKD 1.8 нет. Хотя в Eclipse JDK 1.8 определяется сразу

Comment: @temq на это уведомление не обращайте внимание, это другая проблема, и она не мешает. На счет пути - я выставил jdk1.8.0 в этой форме, но по нажатию на OK и переоктырию этой формы путь снова выставится в jdk1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением оказалось удаление папки C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0.79, в которой AS несмортя на мои уговоры пытался искать jdk, после удаления папки и перезапуска студия сказала что не видит никакой jdk, и предложила указать новый путь, куда я и проставил jdk 8